# How to identify this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given the sequence of numbers:

$$1,~3,~13,~75,~541,~4683,~47293,~545835$$

Find a sequence in an integer parameter $n$ that reproduces the above and could be used to continue the sequence. Any guesses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OEIS is your friend. You can search for sequences there.

There are at least two results:

https://oeis.org/A000670

https://oeis.org/A034172